# TQL: how to do stress testing for a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a SP with a **parameter** that is supposed to be fed **unique value** like '111','112',...

I would like to execute stress testing to compare the latency after adding index.

Is there any sql command or tool can help on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLQueryStress is a free tool for SQL Server programmers. It is designed to assist with performance stress testing of T-SQL queries and routines. The tool automatically collects metrics to help you determine whether your queries will perform under load, and what kind of resource strain they put on your server.

[sql server query performance testing tool](http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/)

Comment: Does anyone know of a similar tool for testing SQL statments via a JDBC connection?